# When would I need to parse JSON data, instead of setting a response type?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm following [this tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON), and I came across this bit:

> But sometimes we aren't so lucky — sometimes we'll receive a raw JSON
>   string, and we'll need to convert it to an object ourselves.

And then they introduced JSON.parse.

The earlier example used `responseType = 'json'`, and it said:

> The above example was simple in terms of accessing the JavaScript
>   object, because we set the XHR request to convert the JSON response
>   directly into a JavaScript object using:
>
> request.responseType = 'json';

But JSON.parse converts it to a JavaScript object, and so does setting the responseType to json. So what's the difference?

What is a 'raw JSON string' as opposed to [this file](https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/javascript/oojs/json/superheroes.json) that was used in the first example, where they set the responseType to json (instead of parsing).

Comment: Raw JSON string is like that file you linked except in string format, something like `'{.....}'` so that it is an actual string and not an object

Comment: @Huangism but JSON IS just a string right? it's not an object anyway?

Comment: Not sure what your question is,.. If you receive some JSON, it's going to be a string. in fact it's going to be a UTF-8 string.  If you get an object, it's because something has converted it for you.  `request.responseType = 'json';` here your telling it to do the converting for you.

Comment: @Keith okay, I get that. so if setting the responseType to json converts it from a string to an object, and using JSON.parse converts it from a string to an object, what's the difference between the two methods? when would I need to use one method over the other?

Comment: @firefiber It's a choice really, let's say we didn't set the response type.  The reason been sometimes it returns an image or text, or something else.  We can then use JSON.parse conditionally.  And we could of course get the JSON from other means, not just HTTP request.